# Как реализовать редиректы в laravel

Tags: laravel

Как реализовать 'модуль' редиректов на laravel?

Добавлена модель, таблица, контроллер.

Таблица:

```
id|from|to
```

В `web.php` в самое начало добавил -

```
Route::get('/{from?}', 'RedirectController@redirect');
```

`RedirectController`

```
public function redirect($from) {
  $redirect = Redirect::where('from', $from)->first();
  if($redirect) {
    return redirect($redirect->to);
  }
}
```

В этом способе есть недостатки:

- любой не существующий адрес выдает пустую страницу `site.ru/333` если
  при проверки существования редирекста он не находит, мы добавим
  `abort`, то он не открывает существующие ссылки `site.ru/index`.
- Не работает если в `from` используются url с несколькими `/` например
  если добавить в `from` адрес типа `category/name_category`    он ее
  все равно откроет(без редиректа)

Если в `web.php` добавить в самый конец -

```
Route::get('/{from?}', 'RedirectController@redirect');
```

Тогда редирект не происходит на существующие ссылки, например есть есть ссылка `/news` и добавить редирект `/news` -> `/news1` - редирект не произойдет

Или нужно делать редирект через `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

Я реализовывал модуль редиректов через `middleware`. Первая проверка идет на соответствие текущего пути (с учетом домена и без) с таблицей. А также есть возможность указать правила с помощью регулярок в формате `^prefix/(.*)` => `/prefix1/1$`

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Modules\Redirector\Models\Redirect;

class RedirectMiddleware
{
    private $rules;

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        // если ajax или не get запрос, пропускаем сразу же
        if ($request->ajax() || !$request->isMethod('GET')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        $pathWithDomain = sprintf("//%s/%s", $request->getHost(), $request->path());
        $queryString = $request->getQueryString();

        $redirect = Redirect::whereIn('from', [$request->path(), $pathWithDomain])->first();

        if (!is_null($redirect)) {
            $to = $redirect->to . ($queryString ? '?' . $queryString : '');

            return redirect($to, $redirect->code);
        } else if ($this->getRules()->count()) {
            foreach ($this->getRules() as $rule) {
                $isDomainRule = $this->isDomainRule($rule->from);
                $url = $isDomainRule ? $pathWithDomain : $request->path();

                if ($this->isCheckRule($url, $rule->from)) {
                    return redirect($this->replaceUrl($url, $rule->from, $rule->to), $rule->code);
                }
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    private function getRules(): Collection
    {
        return $this->rules
            ?: $this->rules = Cache::remember('redirects.rules', now()->addDay(), function () {
                return Redirect::where('is_rule', true)->orderByDesc('priority')->get();
            });
    }

    /**
     * Проверяет, сработало ли правило
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param string $rule
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isCheckRule($url, string $rule)
    {
        return (bool)preg_match("<{$rule}>iu", $url);
    }

    /**
     * Проверяет, является ли правило доменным
     * В бд при добавлении правил и редиректов доменные всегда имеют два слеша вначале,
     * обычные не имеют слешей в начале
     *
     * @param string $rule
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isDomainRule(string $rule)
    {
        return (bool)preg_match('!^//!i', $rule);
    }

    /**
     * @param $url
     * @param $rule
     * @param $to
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function replaceUrl($url, $rule, $to)
    {
        return preg_replace("<" . $rule . ">iu", $to, $url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Решил проблему через `.htaccess`

Также присутствует модель, таблица, контроллер

В файла `.htaccess` добавил `#dbredirect` для отслеживания места, куда нужно вставить текст

`store`

```
$from = $request->input('from');//Получаем адрес 'От'
$to = $request->input('to');//Получаем адрес 'К'
$id = Redirect::create($request->all());//Создаем запись в бд
if($id) {//Если запись создалась
  $handle=fopen('.htaccess', 'r');//Открываем фаил для чтения .htaccess
  $new_text = '';//Создаем пустую переменную
  while(!feof($handle)){//Перебираем фаил
    $new_text .= fgets($handle);//Помещаем текст из файла в переменную
    if (strpos($test, '#dbredirect') !== false) {//Ищем в каждой строке #dbredirect
      $new_text .= '    Redirect 301 '.$from.' '.$to.'
';//Когда находим, сразу после #dbredirect добавляем Redirect 301 ...
    }
}
fclose($handle);//Закрываем фаил
$hand=fopen('.htaccess', 'w');//Открываем фаил для перезапись
fwrite($hand, $new_text);//Помещаем наш новый текст
fclose($hand);//Закрываем фаил
```

`update`

```
$from = $request->input('from');//Получаем адрес 'От'
$to = $request->input('to');//Получаем адрес 'К'
$old_from = $redirect->from;//Получаем адрес 'От' из бд
$handle=fopen('.htaccess', 'r+');//Открываем фаил для чтения .htaccess
$new_text = '';//Создаем пустую переменную
while(!feof($handle)){//Перебираем фаил
  $text = fgets($handle);//Помещаем строку из файла в переменную
  if (strpos($text, '301 '.$old_from) !== false) {//Ищем в строке содержание 301 'старая урл из бд'
    $new_text .= '    Redirect 301 '.$from.' '.$to.'//Если находим, то заменяем на новые адреса
';
  } else {
    $new_text .= $text;//Если не находим, то просто помещаем каждую строку в переменную
  }
}
fclose($handle);//Закрываем фаил
$hand=fopen('.htaccess', 'w');//Открываем фаил для перезапись
fwrite($hand, $new_text);//Помещаем наш новый текст
fclose($hand);//Закрываем фаил
$redirect->update($request->all());//Обновляем бд
```

Comment: не надо из приложения трогать `.htaccess`. Он кешируется браузерами.
`middleware` справится с этой задачей

Comment: @МаксимК Можно пример с middleware?